# Making a light source invisible to everything except shadow rays

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I saw this in [another answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38637/1853) and I would like to know how to do it:

"Making a light source invisible to everything except shadow rays will cause it to only block light from other light sources and not influence anything else."

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

### Materials nodes:

[image]

### Ray visibility:

[image]

Using these *ray visibility* checkboxes instead of nodes will speed up render times a little, however you lose the flexibility of nodes.