# Change Darkness/color of shadow?

Tags: shaders

So I'm working on a project, and the shadows of a CGI cube are a different hue than the other (real) shadows in the footage, as you can tell here:
[image]
Though it can probably pass as "good enough" it will bug me every time I see it.
I would like this shade to match the other shadows.

Settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making very hard shadows softer?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/making-very-hard-shadows-softer)

Comment: Make the surrounding environment (or world) have some of the color that you want for the shadows.

Comment: How is this question duplicate of linked one ? This question is about *hue / color* of shadow, the linked one is about *hardness / softness* of shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much about the lighting, but about the surface of the plane that receives the shadow. If you add a tan/yellow material to the plane, it will show a tan/yellow shadow in the final result. As a general rule, do make your shadow-receiving plane the same color as the ground.