# How do I make a cartoonish material in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm trying to make a stylized material like this:
[image]

I want to bake it eventually so I can only do it in cycles, but I can't seem to get anything close, this is my closest render but the shadows are so soft (unlike the picture) and the material doesn't feel the same.
[image]

These are the materials I'm using ->
[image]

Here's my blender file:
[image]

Comment: I think this question is poorly worded or at least focusing on the wrong part of the problem. This doesn't seem to be much about materials, if at all. The main issue seems to be shadows and lighting which has been covered extensively https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/meaning-of-sun-lamp-size https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33871/is-there-really-a-way-to-make-a-true-toon-shader-material-in-cycles/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/making-very-hard-shadows-softer

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Sorry I didn't know lighting was the biggest issue, and thank you I will look into those posts.

Comment: No problem, if non of those solve the issue, please edit your question with further details of what went wrong

Comment: when you think about it, shadows come from light in real life, surface will only have a small influence on them ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per help from the comments, I did not have to change my materials, just my lighting. I used a sun light and a power of 12 and now it looks very cartoonish as I wanted with solid shadows.