# Combine Filmic Blender and "Standard" Film Emulation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, workflow, color-management, lut

Is it possible to combine the very helpful [filmic-blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im) Color Management with the default Blender Color Management? It helps a lot to light the scenes with the filmic contrast settings, but when it comes to artistic composition and you want to use the benefits of using both troy_s's Settings and the default film emulation, you have to stop your work, close blender, replace the ocio files, restart blender and so on.

Is there a better way to work this out? Is it maybe possible to use the film emulation settings as compositing nodes, similar to a filter in PS or Gimp?

I hope my question is not too stupid. Maybe there is a more elegant workflow to use both, the filmic-blender function and the default film emulation.

Comment: you have to copy the luts you want to the Luts folder, then edit the config.ocio to have the transforms that you need.

Comment: You need integrate de definitions of displays and looks within the oclo.config to include the options you want to use. Read section 4 of this related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/66600/1853

Comment: Hi cetagon, thanks for the reply. Sorry, but i'm coming from an artistic side, and i don't no about how to manipualte / edit blender Systems files. How can i achive the desired result? What type of editor do i have to use? Thank you !

Comment: Look for the files config.ocio, open them in a text editor. The definitions of **displays** and **looks** are in the form of a "stanza" Take the ones from the regular blender config.ocio and add them to the one from the "filmic blender"

Comment: I think this'll give a bit more info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rj1-TuWsd7Y

Comment: Yes yes yes!! Thank you man, this is exactly what i meant ! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rj1-TuWsd7Y

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> but when it comes to artistic composition and you want to use the benefits of using both troy_s's Settings and the default film emulation

I am going to guess that you mean the existing looks. I would advise against them, simply because they are not reliably actually delivering film emulation. That is, the data they were sourced from *was* actual data, however the way in which they are applied is incorrect. They are effectively random Instagram filters with no meaning. If you mean the ridiculous "Film" transform, it is utterly broken with a horrible label.

That sums up to both groups of transforms as effectively being technically meaningless, and as a result would conflict with the goals and technical output of the filmic-blender set.

> you have to stop your work, close blender, replace the ocio files, restart blender and so on.

While true that a restart is required due to how Blender was designed when OCIO was added, it should be pointed out that Blender will respect the OCIO environment variable. Example:

```
export OCIO=/path/to/config.OCIO
```

While it is still a pinch point, this technique might make remote rendering etc. easier for some.

> Is there a better way to work this out? Is it maybe possible to use the film emulation settings as compositing nodes, similar to a filter in PS or Gimp?

GIMP is broken in many horrible ways that I won't go into, and will remain that way into the foreseeable future. No it is not feasible nor doable without many contortions.

Photoshop as well, while not completely broken as GIMP is, is also strictly a display referred imaging application and makes these sorts of transforms challenging at the base level. It *can* read some LUT formats, but it is likely complex to list the events here.

What exactly are you hoping for out of the "Film Emulation" set and I can take a look at it.

Again though, I am reluctant to include random knob twiddling in the set, as I am already faced with two design directions (Views vs Looks) that pull against each other.

Comment: Hi Troy, thank you for your reply; unfortunately your hint using an environment variable did not help me. I'm not into programming stuff and do not know how to use is.

Comment: It is a simpler way of enabling various OCIO configurations. If you give a hint as to what platform you are on perhaps others can help.

Comment: Regarding the film emulation i mean the existing looks. I honor that you, quote, "advise against them", but for me they are - at the current state of knowledge - helpful. Some costumers like that style, so i think in terms of commercial purposes it is ok to use them. Is there a better solution? Sorry, i am just at the beginning of the whole topic and need to learn. My idea was to render out images using the advantages of the filmic-blender transform, and do post processing on the basis of this withour changing the ocio manually. Is this possible ? Tank you.

Comment: You could save to a display referred output such as a TIFF, and then load the result in the compositor and apply the results. Not sure how it will look. If there are a few particular looks you are using, I could be more specific. Which filmic looks?

Comment: @troy_s I believe the OP is referring to the set of "looks" that come as part of the default config.ocio emulating old Agfa, Kodak and Fuji films.

Comment: Yes, cetagon, that is what i meant. The film looks Canon Optura, Kodak Portra etc. I use them often, but only in a sublte way, means that i use a "clear" render, and combine it with a "flim look" using blend modes. This works - as far a i know - not in Blender, and this was the main intention behind my first question. But the more i learn here, the more it seems to me that this way of getting a special "crisp" and contrast to the image is simply wrong. A Film Emulation is not the same as control image contrast. Am i on the right way?