# There is no Film color management in blender 2.8. Why?

Tags: color-management

It's a pity but there is no Film (not Filmic) color management in blender 2.8. I wonder why it was removed? Also all camera presets also were removed. If anybody knows the reason why it was removed and will it be in final 2.8 release, please explain. Thanks.

Comment: This is an opinion, not an answer. I believe it's completely right for Blender, or any other application, to seek to create an interface to its core capabilities, which has a consistent philosophy that can be learned by its users, and is **minimal** and **complete**. The Color Management system approaches that ideal. If there is a demand for _particular ways_ of using the system, that's a good candidate for an add-on. If you don't make that distinction, you're inviting bloat. I think, for example, some of Adobe's and Autodesk's products are guilty of that; you need a dictionary to use them.

Answer (score 3):

The "Film" options was removed because it wasn't proper color management and the "Looks" because they were more of a post-processing filter to achieve a certain appearance. You can still achieve similar results by using the compositor to color grade your renders.

See: [Combine Filmic Blender and "Standard" Film Emulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66957/combine-filmic-blender-and-standard-film-emulation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Of course I can use compositor, but it's more complicated and not so comfortably.

Comment: @supermaximus You can use a hacky workaround described here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146971/can-i-get-back-film-emulation-looks-into-2-80 Be aware though that this may break things and not work correctly at all times.