# Can I get back film emulation looks into 2.80?

Tags: filmic-blender

Just really hoping there is a way to do it, but is it possible to get back film looks for 2.80?

or people who would argue that you can still do it with composite nodes, yes, I understand you can, but that also means I need to know what exactly I want to achieve, I can't ever test a bunch of moods, then tweak it (which was my workflow so far), it's like adding 3 days more work just to see which one I like the most.....  i thought blender was supposed to be the fast option.....

I'm prepared to try to do some python, but I'm at a level where I can only botch things together....

Thanks

Comment: They don’t work. By “don’t work” they are of limited dynamic range and they end up muddling up where middle grey ends up. They are a tiny bit worse than canned Instagram filters, but with random garbage output.

Answer (score 2):

*Warning: The following approach may currently work, but it's not officially supported and may cause bugs and/or crashes when running Blender.*

For this you need a copy of Blender 2.79b which you can download [here](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/). Use one of the appropriate one for your OS that comes as archive (.zip, tar.bz2, tar.gz). We will need this to get the old color management files.

1. Open the directory where you have Blender 2.8 installed and navigate to `2.80/datafiles`. There should be a directory named `colormanagement`. Rename this to `colormanagement_new`.
2. Extract Blender 2.79b archive somewhere on your system. Navigate to `2.79/datafiles` and copy the `colormanagement` directory <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
3. The back to the directory of the Blender 2.8 and paste into `2.80/datafiles` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. You should now see the old options in the color management panel when running Blender 2.8.

If you want to revert the changes simply delete the directory you copied into `2.80/datafiles` and rename `colormanagement_new` back to `colormanagement`.

[image: Blender 2.8 with old color management looks]