# How to use 3d LUT for strips in the video sequential editor?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, video-sequence-editor

How to use 3d LUT for strips in the video sequential editor?

I know that there is no such function. But I think it's possible to create an addon. How can this be done? I do not know the blender api well, so I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65948/how-to-make-3d-luts-and-use-them-in-blender