# Is there a way to adapt False Color to be seen for color blind people?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, color, shadows, color-management

I have severe red/green protonopia and find the red and green to be the same when I use False Color mode to calibrate lighting exposure.

I'm wondering if there is a way to get numeric feedback on parts of a surface I point at or a way to change the colors used in False Color so that I may be able to see them better. Also if not I'm wondering where I could recommend these kind of features.

It would be nice to have a tooltip with a numeric representation of the exposure of where on a surface I am pointing, or shift the colors represented somehow.

Comment: The *False Color* view transform is defined in the [`filmic_false_color.spi3d`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic/filmic_false_color.spi3d) and referenced by the OCIO configuration in [`config.ocio`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/colormanagement/config.ocio). It's entirely possible to replace this with a more suitable colormap, e.g. Viridis, Inferno or [Turbo](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/08/turbo-improved-rainbow-colormap-for.html).

Comment: However I'll have to check how to auto-generate the LUT. The basic format is [described here by Troy Sobotka](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65948/how-to-make-3d-luts-and-use-them-in-blender) (the developer of Filmic)

Comment: I've got a script ready, will likely write the answer tomorrow.

Comment: @Robert Gützkow Wow thank you! I look forward to it a lot. This is a level of technicality that is quite a bit above me right now looking at these links. Its always kind of strange to me how often red and green are used in things when they are in the highest frequency of color deficiency. This could probably be useful to many people who struggle more than they want to admit.

Comment: I hope my answer is helpful. Since I'm not affected by color vision deficiency, it's hard for me to judge whether the lookup tables provide a good solution for this particular use case. It might be necessary to create distinct ranges similar to the original false color view transform for a better solution.

Answer (score 18):

The *False Color* view transform is defined in the [`filmic_false_color.spi3d`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic/filmic_false_color.spi3d) and referenced by the OCIO configuration in [`config.ocio`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/colormanagement/config.ocio). In order to add custom 3D lookup tables as new view transforms, they have to be stored in the `.spi3d` format and the `config.ocio` has to be modified to references these new files.

---

**Update 2020-02-17**: The re-write of the tool is complete. It now includes a proper command line interface, it allows to create your own colormaps or to load colormaps from viscm. The release includes lookup tables that should be suitable for people with color vision deficiency. Turbo has been removed from the list of colormaps since it's not useful for people with achromatopsia and it would require to license all code under the Apache license. The matplotlib colormaps are still available.

**Update 2020-02-05:** The correct mapping of middle grey to the center of the colormap is applied and relative luminance is used for the mapping.

**Update 2020-02-04:** The lookup tables now have a distinct color for both the low and high clipping range.

---

I've implemented a [lookup table generator](https://github.com/robertguetzkow/false-color-lut) that allows you to create your own false color view transforms. Detailed instructions for the installation, colormap creation, arguments for the command line interface and integration into Blender are provided in the [README.md](https://github.com/robertguetzkow/false-color-lut/blob/master/README.md).

The first release also includes two false color view transforms, *Ignis* and *Agnoscis*, designed for people with color vision deficiency using [viscm](https://github.com/matplotlib/viscm). Additionally they've been analyzed with [Coblis](https://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/). The generated `.spi3d` files and custom `ocio.config` can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/robertguetzkow/false-color-lut/releases).

---

**Examples**

[image: Test Scene]
*Test Scene - View Transform: Filmic*

[image: Ignis False Color View Transform]
*Test Scene - View Transform: False Color Ignis*

[image: Agnoscis False Color View Transform]
*Test Scene - View Transform: False Color Agnoscis*

[image: Dante False Color View Transform]
*Test Scene - View Transform: False Color Dante (based on Inferno)*

[image: Ignis Evaluation]
*Ignis Evaluation*

[image: Agnoscis Evaluation]
*Agnoscis Evaluation*

[image: Ignis Exposure Values to Colors]
[image: Agnoscis Exposure Value to Colors]

*Exposure value to color, Ignis (l) and Agnoscis (r)*

---

**Installation**

1. Download the `.spi3d` files and custom `ocio.config` from the [release page](https://github.com/robertguetzkow/false-color-lut/releases).
2. Open Blender's directory and navigate to `[2.8x]\datafiles\colormanagement` (the 2.8x is a placeholder for your Blender version).
3. Rename the original `ocio.config` in that directory, e.g. to `ocio_old.config`
4. Copy the custom `ocio.config` into the `[2.8x]\datafiles\colormanagement` directory
5. Create a directory/folder named `custom` in `[2.8x]\datafiles\colormanagement`
6. Copy the `.spi3d` files into `[2.8x]\datafiles\colormanagement\custom`

---

**Usage**

The new view transforms should be available in *Render Properties > Color Management > View Transforms* after a successful installation.

[image]

Comment: I wanna upvote this like a thousand times! You're awesome :).

Comment: I look very much forward to test this out and provided feedback. I don't have time a whole lot for the next 48 hours but maybe after midnight I could test with it. For me the Magma and Turbo are very clear for finding more ideal exposure. I think I could switch to standard False color to find the extreme spots and then to Magma to see the mids. False Color all becomes just one color I'm almost entirely blind to it but I can see the very extreme white and red(I think). I will be tinkering with this a bit in the future and see if I can make a red protonopia specific solution. This helps a ton

Comment: @SunlightSwift Great! I would appreciate to get feedback. If this works really well, perhaps it could be included in Blender. Perhaps Troy has some suggestions as well.

Comment: If there's a next update it should improve the recognizability of the different exposure values. The color selection also needs to take the middle grey of 0.18 scene referred linear value into account.

Comment: Ok. This is excellent work as is typical of @RobertGützkow. Now take it further; write up a false colour with palettes specifically targeting tritanopia, deuteranopia, and protanopia. There are good formulas for deriving decent mixtures for each, and it should be feasible to implement a good series of increments to correspond with the EV increments under the traditional False Colour. Especially given that there's an audience to test the results. Excellent work.

Comment: I've pushed a repo that has a False Colour generator and the commands to GitHub. It is done using a Colour Ramp node, so should be more or less usable for a majority of people and only relies on the OCIO tool "ociolutimage". Good luck. https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender/tree/make-false-colour

Comment: I've got a new version of the script in development that allows to create custom false color 3D LUTs from specific colors at given exposure values. The updated script and new false color LUTs will likely be released within the current week.

Comment: Yeah being able to tweak it myself would help immensely. Switching between the modes can help a little a few situations, especially turbo for me, but I feel like it could be very very good if specific color values could be clamped to exposure ranges. I am looking forward to these developments a lot and I really appreciate it. Its difficult to do these kinds of things and it disheartens a lot of artists probably a lot more than they say probably with visual difficulties. Hopefully with more tools helping with these things it'll encourage artists to press on despite difficulties. Thanks everyone

Comment: @SunlightSwift The updated script will allow you to define your own colormaps with specific colors at given exposure values. However it will not contain tools to create perceptually uniform colormaps, because that is a lot more complicated. If you're interested in that, you could try to use `viscm` as described in the matplotlib colormaps link.

Comment: I still need to polish the documentation, create examples and images. Hopefully it's done tomorrow.

Comment: The new CLI tool is now online.

Comment: If you have suggestions for colormaps or lookup tables that you would like to see included in the project, please create a [feature request](https://github.com/robertguetzkow/false-color-lut/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Damn, you went that far above and beyond the call of duty and didn't get an accept? <<wipes away a tear while upvoting>>