# How do you change the "False Color" colormap?

Tags: color

I am testing the Color Management option to show an image with the setting of "False Color", which shows, for example, the following image:

[image: False color in Blender]

It's a colormap according to the scene's luminance; red, orange, and yellow regions are highly illuminated, while blue, purple and black are barely, or not at all, as shown in the following image of the same scene but with a "Filmic" color profile:

[image: Filmic profile in Blender]

The problem:

**Is there a way the change the colormap** (or color ramp) for another one? For example, **is there a way to remove that gray circle in the middle of the green area?** (which according to [this source](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/secret-ingredient-photorealism) stands for the middle gray value.)

**Where does that color map resides within Blender? Can it be changed like if it was a color ramp node?**

The official Blender documentation page doesn't give any information on this particular topic. It barely mentions the "False color" feature.

(Yes, I know one can render the image as pure luminance, like the black & white one, and then apply a ColorRamp node in the compositing node tree, however, I would like to use this "false color" feature in real time (with my own colors), while working with Blender for setting up lights' and objects' positions, not necessarily for rendering a final image. Having control of the color ramp would allow me to adjust some luminance thresholds, therefore higher precision work would be possible.)

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to adapt False Color to be seen for color blind people?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165722/78972)

Comment: There's the answer. Thank you very much Jachym.