# Highlight compression (Blender/Cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, color-management

Does anyone have a smooth way of highlight compression in the Blender/Cycles settings, or in Compositor? The only compressor i have found so far is the Tonemap-Node in Compositor, and i find its settings very hard to control and never get the desired result.

Thanks!

Comment: "the desired result"... that is an elusive term. Are you using filmic? Try the different "looks"

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im

Comment: "Desired result" was put in context with the term highlight compression i hoped. In After Effects, Corona, Vray, ... the term means simplified leaving the image appearance just as is, but use the highlight compression value to dial in those few local hotspots which are burning out. Mostly sunlight or really narrow spots.

Comment: ... one could open up the question for a versatile tonemapper such as Reinhard, which is compressing the highlights as well. Anything that is in there is ok for me, sure it is just me not finding it as it is a quite basic functionality with renderers and compositors in general.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65948/how-to-make-3d-luts-and-use-them-in-blender

Comment: Thanks, but i am not looking for a Look but for simple primary highlight compression.

Comment: You can do that with a LUT

Comment: So you do it that way? I would like to understand, as burning highlights are scene dependent and require tweaking a lot. It's a bit like creating a solid color texture map for controlling diffuse color, getting the job done but exhausting after the 20th tweak. So is everyone doing tonemapping with LUTs in blender?