# Increase the contrast of shadows like you would using a color ramp

Tags: shaders

Is it possible to increase the contrast of shadows the way you would with a color ramp, but without effecting the colors themselves? I don't want hard edges, and color ramps allow you to have a middle ground

[image]

The reason I just want to affect the contrast of shadows, is that I would like to try combining higher contrast shadows with other types of shaders, or things like subsurface scattering.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). By 'increase the contrast' you mean *darker* shadows? Or are you talking about ambient occlusion?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/how-can-i-cast-artificially-darker-shadows

Comment: I mean contrast as in defining how smooth the transition between light and dark is.
toon shading would be 100% light and 100% shadow, with no smooth transition between the two. A middle ground is like the image above, where there is a small smooth transition between light and shadow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this setup to control the contrast of the shadows. In the image I provide, I mix the shadows with a texture, but you can use a color just the same. Also, because my example is for toon shading, I have the ColorRamp set to "constant", you probably want something more like "Linear", "B-spline", or "Ease". Lastly, the reason I multiplied it twice was to darken the shadows even further because they didn't turn out well in screenshots. Use as needed.

[image: ContrastShadows]